# Round up to a smoother number

Tags: code-golf

## Input

Two positive integers `a > b`

## Output

The smallest integer `c >= a` so that `c` can be factored into two parts with one part an integer power of two (that is at least two) and the other part no larger than `b`.

## Examples

If `b = 100` and `a = 101` , then the output should be 102 as 102 is 2 times 51.

For the same `b`, if `a = 201` then the output should be 204 as that equals 4 times 51.

For the same `b`, if `a = 256` then the output should be 256.

Comment: What's wrong with 202*1 for the second test case? Does the multiple of 2 need to be smaller than the other part?

Comment: @TheThonnu 202 is greater than b in that case. It has to factorisable into two parts as described in the question

Comment: 202 is the multiple of 2 and 1 is less than b if I'm understanding the question correctly

Comment: There was a typo. It should have said power of two. Thank you for spotting that. Fixed now

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

Expects `(b)(a)` as either numbers or BigInts (ES11).

```javascript
b=>g=a=>a/(a&-a)>b?g(-~a):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/J1i7dNtHWLlFfI1FNN1HTLsk@XUO3LlHTKvF/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoahgYEmkDDU1OTCImGEU8LUTFPzPwA)

#### How?

We recursively increment `a` while `a / (a & -a)` is greater than `b`.

The bitwise trick `a & -a` isolates the least significant `1` in the binary representation of `a`, i.e. the largest divisor or `a` which is a power of 2.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 8 bytes

```
L/.²îoƶß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fR1/v0KbD6/KPbTs8//9/QwMDLiMDQwA)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
L/.²îïoƶß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fR1/v0KbD6w6vzz@27fD8//8NDQy4jAwMAQ)

`ï` is now needed due to a bug, since `o` takes forever without it.

### Explanation

Goes over all possible values \$d\$ in \$c = d 2^s\$, by looking at the first power of \$2\$ which is \$\geq \lceil \frac a d \rceil\$.

```
L       range [1, 2, 3, ..., b]
/       [a/1, a/2, a/3, ..., a/b]
.²      [log2(a/1), log2(a/2), ..., log2(a/b)]
î       [ceil(log2(a/1)), ceil(log2(a/2)), ..., ceil(log2(a/b))]
o       [2^ceil(log2(a/1)), 2^ceil(log2(a/2)), ..., 2^ceil(log2(a/b))]
ƶ       [1*2^ceil(log2(a/1)), 2*2^ceil(log2(a/2)), ..., b*2^ceil(log2(a/b))]
ß       min([1*2^ceil(log2(a/1)), 2*2^ceil(log2(a/2)), ..., b*2^ceil(log2(a/b))])
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>38</del> 37 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to the comment of @xnor

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYwxC8IwFIT3/Io3yXtYMRF0KLTg6OAkTuLwWpOSEqOkQZDS3x5TZz24g7sPbmjZcXo0vW4jHNl6GIV4sQNT4sHHIpuqOidUkLApODdrEHmNK14wUd2QmfelIu0GDZwAbtrAPX8hh24oYR8Cvy@nGKzvrlTC2dv5bhSQ9cxrdB4NKikLUFIR/QKbv2C7@4JJTOkD)

```scala
(b,a)=>if((a/(-a&a))>b)f(b,a+1)else a
```

Comment: It looks like you can write `(-a&a)`

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `M`, 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
R/Æḷ€ṃOż×
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPXJhbmdlJTIwJTJGJTIwbG9nMiUyMCVFMiU4MiVBQyUyMGNlaWwlMjB0d29fcG93ZXIlMjBsZW5ndGhfcmFuZ2Vfbm9fcG9wJTIwdGltZXMmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xMDAlMEEyMDEmZmxhZ3M9dk0=)

Port of Command Master's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
R/Æḷ€ṃOż×  # Implicit input
R/         # Divide b by [1..a]
  Æḷ       # Log base 2 of each
    €ṃ     # Ceiling of each
      O    # Two power of each
       ż×  # Multiply by index
           # Take the minimum
           # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 46  bytes

```javascript
o=a=>a&1n?a:o(a/2n)
f=(a,b)=>o(a)<b?a:f(++a,b)
```

takes big integers as Input

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN_XybRNt7RLVDPPsE63yNRL1jfI0udJsNRJ1kjRt7YACmjZJQJk0DW1tkBBUl29yfl5xfk6qXk5-ukaahqGBYZ6OoYFBnqYmF6qMEW4ZUzOYDMRQmJMA)

### Explanation

`o` gets the odd part of a number (product of all odd prime factors)

`f` increments `a` until its odd part is less than `b`

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔±Ｘ²Ｌ↨⊕÷θ±Ｎ²ζＩ×ζ÷θζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzNCsMgEITveQqPG7BgvObUn0ughBz6AtYsRoim0U0Kvry1tId2LjMMM5@eVNCLmnPu/GOjfnN3DLDWbXWM0RoPPRpFCMPyLL3k7Ire0AQnFRE6rwM69IRjyXSxux0RVs6@p19kXcSZ/Fgq/CFYT3BWkeBmHUZInP1B0nvb5ixFUzVC5MM@vwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `a`.

```
≔±Ｘ²Ｌ↨⊕÷θ±Ｎ²ζ
```

Calculate the smallest power of `2` not less than `a/b`.

```
Ｉ×ζ÷θζ
```

Round `a` up to that power of `2`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Họ¡2’<ð1#
```

A dyadic Link that accepts \$a\$ on the left and \$b\$ on the right and yields \$c\$ as a singleton list. Alternatively, a full program that prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/j4e7eQwuNHjXMtDm8wVD5////hgaGQGwAAA)**

#### How?

```
Họ¡2’<ð1# - Link: integer, a; integer b
       1# - starting at k=a and incrementing find the first k for which:
      ð   -   dyadic chain - f(k, b):
  ¡       -     repeat...
 ọ 2      -     ...times: order-multiplicity 2
H         -     ...action: halve
                  -> divides k by two until we have an odd number
    ’     -     decrement
     <    -     is less than {b}? (i.e. k <= b ?)
```

---

Same method `Bt0Ḅ’<ð1#` or `BTṬḄ’<ð1#` - remove trailing zeros from the binary representation and convert back.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-1`, 7 bytes

```
Ň+ᵖ{ʷ½≥
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpKuoVLsgqWlJWm6FuuOtms_3Dqt-tT2Q3sfdS5dUpyUXAyVWrDd0MBQwdDAgMsIRpuagWiINAA)

```
Ň+ᵖ{ʷ½≥
Ň           Find a natural number
 +          Plus the first input
  ᵖ{        Check that:
    ʷ½        Repeatedly divide by 2 until the number is odd
      ≥       The second input is greater than or equal to the result
```

`-1` prints the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `g`, 57 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.125 bytes

```
ɾ/2•⌈EÞż
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJnPSIsIiIsIsm+LzLigKLijIhFw57FvCIsIiIsIjEwMFxuMjAxIl0=)

Ports the 05AB1E answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [C89](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 36 bytes

*port of [Arnauld's JavaScript (ES6) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263779/112488).*

```c
f(a,b){return(a&-a)*b<a?f(a+1,b):a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BDoIwEETP7Fc0GE2rxVATjQrqj3hZWsAmWAwUL4RftxaIJ0@7eTO7MzIqpXSuoMgz1je57RpDcRUhW2cp3jzfCK@cMRncQhtZdSonaWuVrrePK8C71gps3lqqjSXIyTgyBj0Er8bvBQ2X6m5CTsYIr7AEBgCvwBO1oZNzuhex4ETEsTfMYPcH9ocfgGCuSmL/zn1kUWHZusj3usjj6Qs)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 bytes

*ommiting the return statement and the unchanged trailling parameter in the recursive call*

```c
f(a,b){a=(a&-a)*b<a?f(a+1):a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5NDoIwEIXXzCkajKbVYqiJRgX0Im6GFrAJFgPFDeHq1oJx5epNvveTkVElpXMlRZ6zATOKqwjZOk/x6tlGsDMmo1toI@teFSTtrNLN9n4BeDVagS06S7WxBDmZJGcwQPBs/V3ScKluJuRkGvcOS2AE8A48UBs6J@e@iAUnIo594At2f2B/@AEI2sL2rSGxn3NvWdZYdS7yf2XyePoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 41 bytes

```
f(a,b)=min(2^{ceil(log_2a/L)}L)
L=[1...b]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w2ov82onsz)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wzbablmymr)

Port of 05AB1E